How $u=e^x \cos y, v= e^x \sin y$ give a metric?
From the red line of picture below, I want to know how to get a metric from $u=e^x \cos y, v= e^x \sin y$.
First, I have
$$
du = e^x \cos y dx - e^x \sin y dy = u dx - v dy
\\
dv =e^x\sin y dx + e^x \cos y dy = v dx + u dy 
$$
Then, there are
$$
\begin{align}
&du^2= u^2 dx^2 -v^2 dy^2
\\
&dv^2= v^2 dx^2 + u^2 dy^2
\\
&dudv=uv dx^2 +(u^2-v^2 ) dx dy -uv dy^2
\end{align}
$$
Then, I don't know how to do. In fact, I want to get what $g_{uu}, g_{vv},g_{uv}$ are.




For any $f(u,v)= f(e^x \cos y , e^x \sin y )$, there is
$$
\begin{align}
&\partial_x f= \partial _u f  \partial _x u + \partial _v f  \partial _x v
=   u_x  \partial _u f  +    v_x  \partial _v f
\\
&\partial_y f = \dots
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\partial_x = u_x \partial_u + v_x \partial_v  
\\
\partial_y = u_y \partial_u + v_y \partial_v
$$
Notice $u_x = u, u_y = -v, v_x =v, v_y =u$. There is
$$
\partial_u = \frac{u\partial_x-v\partial_y}{u^2+v^2}
~~~~~~
\partial_v = \frac{v\partial_x+u\partial_y}{u^2+v^2}
$$
It follows
$$
\langle \partial_u , \partial _u \rangle =g(x)e^{-2x}
~~~~~~
\langle \partial_v , \partial _v \rangle =g(x)e^{-2x}
~~~~~~
\langle \partial_u , \partial _v \rangle = 0
$$
But I still don't know why $g(x)$ is a mooth function of $e^{2x}$. Let me think.
